# Check Expiration Date in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, time

I am working in C++11 and am looking to calculate the expiration date of an item based on its issue date. If the item as issued more than 30 days ago, it should be expired:

```
#include <ctime>

bool isExpired() {

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tend = tstart + std::chrono::hours(30 * 24);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    bool expired = tnow >= tend;
    return expired;
}
```

however, I don't seem to be able to concisely input a start date. Some other questions indicated that some like

```
auto ymd = jun/9/2017; // Yields a year_month_day type
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tstart = sys_days(ymd);
```

Might work in C++11 but Xcode certainly doesn't like it and I'm unsure if I'm straddling C++14 and above features.

What is a concise way to perform this calculation in c++11?

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't seem to be able to concisely input a start date"? What's wrong with `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`?

Comment: it might just be me but it looks like your statements in the second piece of code are a bit out of logical order...And what is "tstart" supposed to be inside of your isExpired function?  You are using it without any visible declaration...

Comment: @Rakete1111 I would like to set `tstart` equal to `June 9, 2017`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question ([run it](https://www.ideone.com/RZCYYX)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

bool is_expired( std::chrono::system_clock::time_point issued_time )
{
  using namespace std;
  using namespace std::chrono;
  typedef duration< int, ratio_multiply < hours::period, ratio<24> >::type > days;
  return duration_cast< days >( system_clock::now() - issued_time ) > days { 30 };
}

auto operator""_issued( const char* s ) // see http://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal
{
  std::istringstream iss { s };
  std::tm t {};
  iss >> std::get_time( &t, "%Y%m%d" );
  return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t( std::mktime( &t ) );
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << (is_expired( 20170101_issued ) ? "expired" : "valid") << std::endl;
  std::cout << (is_expired( 22000601_issued ) ? "expired" : "valid") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `auto operator""_` is a c++14 construct for several reasons. Changed to `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> issued_( const char* s )` instead for c++11

Comment: [User defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) is a c++11 addition. A regular function is good as well.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to use [Howard Hinnant's datetime library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) (which is great!).  It doesn't come pre-installed.  Get it from the link above.  For the parts you're using, all you need is the header `"date.h"`, and a `using namespace date;`.

Using the same date.h header, you can also say `days{30}` in place of the expression you have with `hours` if you want.  Either works.

Comment: I'll take a look. My hope was to use plain c++11 only.

Comment: You should add the tagline "making dates great again" to your datetime lib :)